# Modify string variable value befor further processing

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I'm kinda tearing my hair out trying to modify the "UC" into a "UU" stored in my "url" variable.

I need to *only* replace the very first UC in the string, any subsequent match must be ignored

This is my code
(The commented line is what does not work sofar :(   )

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var val = document.getElementById('yturl').value;
  var url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=" + val;

  //var url = Str.replace('UC','UU');

  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var linkText = document.createTextNode(url);
  a.appendChild(linkText);
  a.title = "yturl";
  a.target = '_blank';
  a.href = url;
  a.style.display = 'block';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="yturl" value="UCn-K7GIs62ENvdQe6ZZk9-w" />
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="ChannelPlayListURL" />
</form>
```

If replacing this string is to cumbersome,
"slicing" the first two charas and adding a "UU" would also work for me (but slicing didn't work either sadly)

Comment: What have you tried? The only thing that remotely looks like an attempt is commented out. `+ val.replace("UC", "UU")` should do the job

Comment: Where do you set `Str`? Shouldn't that be `val.replace`?

Comment: You should do the replacement before you concatenate to `url`.

Comment: @Phil That's what they said: The commented line is what they tried, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with plain string arguments will only replace the first occurrence.

You should also [encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) any query parameters correctly for use in a URL

```js
const baseUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries";

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // usually a good idea, especially around forms

  // Creates a map of query parameters and encodes them when stringified
  const query = new URLSearchParams({
    list: document.getElementById("yturl").value.replace("UC", "UU"),
  });

  const url = `${baseUrl}?${query}`;

  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.title = "yturl";
  a.target = "_blank";
  a.href = url;
  a.append(url);
  a.style.display = "block";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="yturl" value="UCn-K7GIs62ENvdQe6ZZk9-w" />
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="ChannelPlayListURL" />
</form>
```

Comment: prototype replace, thats neat. Should come in handy in the future. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `//var url = Str.replace('UC','UU');` use `url = url.replace('UC', 'UU')`

or better yet:

`var url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=" + val.replace('UC', 'UU');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the replacement before using `val` when assigning `url`.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var val = document.getElementById('yturl').value;
  val = val.replace('UC', 'UU');
  var url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=" + val;

  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var linkText = document.createTextNode(url);
  a.appendChild(linkText);
  a.title = "yturl";
  a.target = '_blank';
  a.href = url;
  a.style.display = 'block';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="yturl" value="UCn-K7GIs62ENvdQe6ZZk9-w" />
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="ChannelPlayListURL" />
</form>
```